# Css overlay working in Firefox but someting is wrong in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, overlay

if you take a look at this website using FIrefox

www,bloomdesign,rs  (replace both "," with ".")

and if you click on the word "usluge" from the menu, you'll see that everything is fine, but if you do that using Chrome, something is not working. (only from homepage. It works from other pages)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem in Chrome?
Thanks

Comment: This looks like an animation problem in Chrome. The `#gkMenuOverlay` is changing from `opacity: 0;` to `opacity: 1;` correctly, but Chrome only displays the element correctly once you open the Inspector and use it to hover over the `<div id="gkMenuOverlay">`. You could Google for info about the script you're using to achieve this fade in animation, and see if other people are experiencing the same issues, or change the script for one that works more reliably (you could do this in jQuery quite simply, or a mixture of JS and CSS3.)

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other "quick fix" using css?

And where did you find opacity:0 ? I can't find that line anywhere in my css file

Comment: It's not in your CSS file, it's in a `style=""` attribute on the element itself--so I'm assuming it's being added via a script of some kind. Is there a quick fix? Hmm, I'd hedge my bet closer to "no" than "yes" ... I really would Google around for the script you're using to do the hide/show and look for issues/fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to setek, I have found a solution, so I'll post it here in case someone else faces the same problem.

Overlay opacity doesn't work very well with the latest Chrome update (33), so we have to put `opacity: 0.0X`; where X is some number, instead of `opacity: 0;`

I found that code in my js file and replaced

```
overlay.fade('in');
```

with

```
overlay.fade('in'); overlay.setOpacity(0.01) ;
```

Not sure if anyone has the same javascript file, but this is what helped me to solve the problem.